# Where do I put the database constraints in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, validation, constraints

Simple problem. I'm learning RoR. I swear that I searched this theme here and in google.

I need a lot of tables in my app.

I'm reading about the benefits of database constraints. I'm using validations inside every model, example:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :other
  has_one :another...

  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password

  validates :username, e:mail, :password, presence: true
  validades .....
end
```

I would like to know about database constraints, how can i get the same validation inside the database? Should i put this constraints (like `:null => false`) inside the schema.rb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely put that in your migration:

`:null => false`

To require a non-empty field. Although an empty string can still be supplied and it passes the non-`NULL` test. You can cover this by adding a length validation:

`validates_length_of :username, :minimum => 1, :maximum => 255`

Comment: To further clarify this answer, put that in your MIGRATION file, not in the SCHEMA.RB file, since that last one is autogenerated, and it will be overwritten.

Comment: always write migrations, as Rails updates schema.rb based on the migrations you run